# Stopwatch / Timer, save var and show in high score list (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, stopwatch, web-storage

I'm building a web application that needs a timer: Start, stop, and reset at a specific event. After these I want to save the variable in something like a "highscore" list.

The app is supposed to be used with a AR Glasses for maintenance jobs.

The app should include the feature that the duration of the jobs should be measured.

This is the code that is relevant to my problem:

JS:

```
 var    clsStopwatch = function() {
            // Private vars
            var startAt = 0;    // Time of last start / resume. (0 if not running)
            var lapTime = 0;    // Time on the clock when last stopped in milliseconds

        var now = function() {
                return (new Date()).getTime(); 
            }; 

        // Public methods
        // Start or resume
        this.start = function() {
                startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
            };

        // Stop or pause
        this.stop = function() {
                // If running, update elapsed time otherwise keep it
                lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
                startAt = 0; // Paused
            };

        // Reset
        this.reset = function() {
                lapTime = startAt = 0;
            };

        // Duration
        this.time = function() {
                return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0); 
            };
    };

var x = new clsStopwatch();
var $time;
var clocktimer;
var ourTime = 3;

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "0000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length - size);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var h = m = s = ms = 0;
    var newTime = '';

    h = Math.floor( time / (60 * 60 * 1000) );
    time = time % (60 * 60 * 1000);
    m = Math.floor( time / (60 * 1000) );
    time = time % (60 * 1000);
    s = Math.floor( time / 1000 );
    ms = time % 1000;

    newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2) + ':' + pad(ms, 3);
    return newTime;
}

function show() {
    $time = document.getElementById('time');
    update();
}

function update() {
    $time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
}

function start() {
    clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
    x.start();
}

function stop() {
    x.stop();
    clearInterval(clocktimer);
}

function reset() {
    stop();
    x.reset();
    update();
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stopwatch</title>
</head>
<body onload="show();">
    <div>Time: <span id="time"></span></div>
    <input type="button" value="start" onclick="start();">
    <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop();">
    <input type="button" value="reset" onclick="reset()">
</body>


<div id="result"></div>


<script>
  if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", ourTime);
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}



</script>
```

In this example the value `3` is saved and displayed correctly, but I can't display the time after the stopwatch stopped.

The best I came up with is:

```
var ourTime = formatTime(X)
```

This will display a number in the correct format, but the value is always 00:00:00 or undefined. How do I get the correct stopwatch stop value?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you tried to update a field that is not defined; the $time value called in update() is set to NULL. To solve this I declared $time inside start() and now it seems to work. Also you are not using the show() function at all, so I just left it out, just as the localStorage piece, as it does not contribute to the question and xy is not defined, thus it just creates an error for us.

```js
 var clsStopwatch = function() {
   // Private vars
   var startAt = 0; // Time of last start / resume. (0 if not running)
   var lapTime = 0; // Time on the clock when last stopped in milliseconds

   var now = function() {
     return (new Date()).getTime();
   };

   // Public methods
   // Start or resume
   this.start = function() {
     startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
   };

   // Stop or pause
   this.stop = function() {
     // If running, update elapsed time otherwise keep it
     lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
     startAt = 0; // Paused
   };

   // Reset
   this.reset = function() {
     lapTime = startAt = 0;
   };

   // Duration
   this.time = function() {
     return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
   };
 };

 var x = new clsStopwatch();
 var $time;
 var clocktimer;
 var ourTime = 3;

 function pad(num, size) {
   var s = "0000" + num;
   return s.substr(s.length - size);
 }

 function formatTime(time) {
   var h = m = s = ms = 0;
   var newTime = '';

   h = Math.floor(time / (60 * 60 * 1000));
   time = time % (60 * 60 * 1000);
   m = Math.floor(time / (60 * 1000));
   time = time % (60 * 1000);
   s = Math.floor(time / 1000);
   ms = time % 1000;

   newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2) + ':' + pad(ms, 3);
   return newTime;
 }

 function update() {
   $time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
 }

 function start() {
   //Declare $time here, so update() knows which field it needs to update
   $time = document.getElementById('time');
   clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 41);
   x.start();
 }

 function stop() {
   x.stop();
   clearInterval(clocktimer);
 }

 function reset() {
   stop();
   x.reset();
   update();
 }
```

```html
<div>Time: <span id="time"></span></div>
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="start();">
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop();">
<input type="button" value="reset" onclick="reset()">
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I think you misunderstood my question. The timer was working correctly. The problem I have is saving the variable into local storage and displaying the correct value. I changed xy to ourTime.